# How can I read memory from a specific address that's allocated to a different process in OSX?

Tags: c++, c, macos, memory

Let's say that there's a value of interest, and it is located at `address`.  However, this memory is owned by process `a.dylib`.  I won't be able to access this memory through `./code` with `int x = *(int*)address` because `./code` does not own the memory that holds `address`.

How can I access `address` with `./code` in OSX, preferably without root?  Am I required to go through `vm_read()`?

Comment: Possibly of interest:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114319/how-to-access-dev-mem-in-osx

Comment: If you can just read any memery, OSX is a really shitty OS. You probably want some segment of shared memory.

Comment: When you run your program inside the GDB, the GDB owns all the memory and it is reading its own, not another process's.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/jonathan-og/xnumem?

Comment: @dtmilano I saw that before, I forgot about it.  I'll take another look.

Comment: @dtmilano Yeah, so it gives me the same `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` that I got with my own code.